# Haversine Formula Error - Incorrect Distance - Arduino

Tags: arduino, gps, haversine

Currently taking part in a project that requires to take readings from a gps module and then using these calculate the distance between the readings and a fixed waypoint. The Gps works and gives the values of LAT - 54.9289 and LON - -1.368 this should give a distance of about 3,200 meters. however it gives around 6105. I also have a feeling that 6105 is km to haha. Im wondering if its not taking the negative numbers correctly or if i have some variable conflicts in the code. Any light shed on this would be great, thanks.

```
#include <TinyGPS.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <rgb_lcd.h>
#include <Wire.h>

//Sets TX And RX Pins
SoftwareSerial GPS(2,3);
TinyGPS gps;
void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps);
bool feedgps();
void CheckGPS();
void GetCoords();
 long lat, lon;
 float LAT, LON; // Latitude is gained from GPS and stored in another variable to avoid errors - Should change with changing GPS value - Which would alter distance to waypoint.
 float LAT1,LON1;
rgb_lcd lcd;


void setup()
{
// Sets Baud Rate
  GPS.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}
// Determines The Distance Between Current Location And Waypoint

void GetDistance() 
{
  // Calculating Distance Between Waypoints

  double Distance_Lat; // Distance between Lattitude values
  double Distance_Lon; // Distance between Lonitude values
  double Distance_Total = 0;// Total Distance 
  double val,val2; // Subsidary variable for holding numbers. - No actual value represented.
  double fLAT1,fLAT2;
  double LAT2 = 54.900000; // Waypoint Latitude
  double LON2 = -1.368072; // Waypoint Longitude

 // Initialising Calculation
  Distance_Lat = radians(LAT2-LAT1); // Must be done in radians
  fLAT1 = radians(LAT1);
  fLAT2 = radians(LAT2);
  Distance_Lon = radians((LON2)-(LON1));

  // Calculating Distance - Using Haversines Formulae
  Distance_Total = (sin(Distance_Lat/2.0)*sin(Distance_Lat/2.0));
  val = cos(fLAT1);
  val = val*(cos(fLAT2));
  val = val*(sin(Distance_Lon/2.0));
  val = val*(sin(Distance_Lon/2.0));
  Distance_Total = Distance_Total + val;

  Distance_Total = 2*atan2(sqrt(Distance_Total),sqrt(1.0-Distance_Total)); 
  Distance_Total = Distance_Total*6371.0000; // Converting to meters.
Serial.println("Distance: ");
Serial.println(Distance_Total);

  //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}

// Returns Latitude And Longitude As Decimal Degrees (DD).
void GetCoords()
{
 long lat, lon;
  CheckGPS();
  Serial.print("Latitude : ");
  Serial.print(LAT/1000000,7);
  Serial.print(" :: Longitude : ");
  Serial.println(LON/1000000,7);

}

void CheckGPS()

  {
  bool newdata = false;
  unsigned long start = millis();
 // Every 1 seconds, Print an update
  while (millis() - start < 1000)
    {
    if (feedgps ())
    newdata = true;
    if (newdata)
    gpsdump(gps);
    }
  }

// Checks If The GPS Has Any Data To Transmit
  bool feedgps()
  {
    while (GPS.available())
    if (gps.encode(GPS.read()))
      return true;
    else
      return false;  
  }

// Transmits GPS Data And Gets Latitude And Longitude Positions.
  void gpsdump(TinyGPS &gps)

{    gps.get_position(&lat, &lon);
     LAT = lat;
     LON = lon;
     //Keeps The GPS Fed To Avoid Checksum Errors.
     feedgps();

}

void loop()
{
// Function That Returns The GPS Coordinates In DD.
  GetCoords();
  GetDistance();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The haversine formula I'm looking at on Wikipedia at right now, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula, has arcsin(sqrt(Distance_Total)) where you have your atan2.

Comment: Thank you, i think that was the problem as i am now receiving a value of 3052.94 which is fairly close to what it should be.